# Set controls' position quick and get a smooth render

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to develop an application with a "map" and every user has some pieces on it.

All the pieces are in canvas.

The pieces have a new position every 30ms, I set them using a timer doing :
myPiece.Margin = new Thickness(x, y, 0, 0);

But the render is not really smooth (actually it is when I put my window in 1024*768).

Is there a better way to set the positions to have a better render ?

Comment: Do not set element positions by their Margin. Instead, use the `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` attached properties, that were invented for this particular purpose. Alternatively, setting the `RenderTransform` of the elements to an appropriate TranslateTransform may result in slightly better performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try RenderTransform with TranslateTransform. They should be faster than setting the margins. But then you will need to keep track of your positions based on something else but margin.